# How to open a div inside a single card on button click which is in loop

Tags: angular8

I have a card which has ngFor loop, so many cards can create and inside each card I have a button , on button click I am opening a div inside that card. But currently on buton click div is opening in every card as it is in loop. How to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Maintain the proper id's for each div's inside the foreach loop so that it'll expand and collapse properly, for your reference below is the sample html and typescript code.

--.html

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let item of itemList;let i=index;">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row bg-light" (click)="onClick(item,i,item.collapsed)"
        [attr.aria-expanded]="item.collapsed" aria-controls="item.name">
           <div class="col background-grey">
             <label>{{item.name}}</label>
           </div>
     </div>

    <div id="{{item.name}}" [collapse]="item.collapsed" [isAnimated]="true" class="container">
    // content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

--.ts

```
itemList = [];

ngOnInit() {
 for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
    const objItem = {name:'name'+i,collapsed:true};
    this.itemList.push(objItem);
  }
}

onClick(item,index,collapsed){
   this.itemList[index].collapsed = !collapsed;
}
```